# Possibility of setting up a generic wireless modem and use an ISP's SIM card at home

Tags: modem, gateway, antenna

I'm planning to set up either a home modem or mobile modem to use in our home. This would be connected to an external antenna, and will use either prepaid or postpaid SIM card.

Current requirements:

- The modem must be connected to an external antenna to get a better signal.
- The modem must be using a SIM card that can be either prepaid or postpaid for ease of use.
- It is similar to USB Modems but would have be connected to an external antenna.

Is this type of connection possible?

Comment: All of this is possible, both usb and non-usb 4G modems can have external antennas - it is just a case of purchasing one with the option.  So (1) is "yes" and (2) is off topic as it is a shopping question.

Comment: Yes, but you're voting to close a question based on something completely outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Would there be a problem for the antenna part? Maybe, ISPs broadcast internet to different frequencies. ISP A is broadcasting to a low frequency, while ISP B is broadcasting to a high frequency. Swapping of SIMs might means re-assigning the antenna to a certain frequency. Or the antenna might be a catch-all which means no configuring at all, just plug it like the antenna TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several networking manufacturers that make equipment that will allow you to use a mobile broadband connection as your primary internet connection.

[D-link](https://www.dlink.co.nz/home-solutions/mobile-broadband/3g-4g-lte-desktop-routers), [TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com/sa/products/list-4691.html), and [Netgear](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/mobile-broadband/#tab-hotspots) are but a few that will do what you need.

Like Jake mentioned, you might find that the restrictive part of this set up is the ISP. Whether they will allow you to do it this way or not is entirely up to them. Although I think it would be in their interest to allow this, as mobile broadband is often much more expensive to buy that an xDSL or Fibre solution.

Comment: Thanks. My problem now is the modem signal reception. I guess the **antennae** for the devices of the main brands above are for transmitting WiFi signal, not receiving wireless/cellular signal. It might be similar to a USB Modem in terms of signal reception because of having no external antenna. I might buy one from those devices soon. However, can you identify this [Huawei device](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/smart-home/lte-router/features/b315-en.htm) if its 2-port antenna is for the modem for receiving cellular signal or for the router for transmitting wifi signal?

Comment: Why not both? I have no idea, and their "specification" page has very little usable information on it. I don't see any reason why the ports *couldn't* be used for the LTE connection, but I have no way of knowing that from the information at hand.

Comment: According to the [Product Description PDF](http://download-c1.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=19871&siteCode=worldwide) (link will directly download the pdf), the external antennas are indeed for the LTE connection.

Comment: Does it mean that 2 ports are dedicated in receiving cellular/LTE signal? So how can the modem router transmit WiFi signal? Does it have an internal antenna inside for transmitting WiFi?

Comment: Yes, it does include internal antennas, as stated in the PDF I link.